# How to refactor render from rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, refactoring, render

```
  def create
    render json: '{"error": "400"}', status: :bad_request and return if post_params[:post].blank?
    ...and more general create code....       
  end


  def update
    render json: '{"error": "400"}', status: :bad_request and return if post_params[:post].blank? 
     ...and more general update code.... 
  end
```

How can I refactor out the render error 400 line above, from the create and update actions so that I do not repeat myself?

This validation will be used all over my code, and I would just like to include it in my actions.

when I create a method, such as this:

```
  def validations
    render json: '{"error": "400"}', status: :bad_request and return if post_params[:post].blank?       
end
```

I see an error:

```
AbstractController::DoubleRenderError (Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".):
  app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:43:in `create'
```

... not present when the code is simply written as is above.

Answer (score 0):

The json keys being returned are redundant with the statuses and don't make much sense. Use something that returns a consistent key and possibly put some more useful information in the return string.

```
def create
  if post_params[:post].blank?
    render json: '{"status": "400"}', status: :bad_request
  else 
    .. do general create things
    render json: '{"non-error?": "200"}', status: 200
  end      
end


def update
  # basically the same as above 
end
```